# WSO2 Registry 4.6 Lifecycle Demote Issue

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

We are testing out WSO2 Governance 4.6 default lifecycle process and noticed that when we hit "DEMOTE" button nothing happens!
I mean it says Lifecycle operation executed successfully, but it does actually do any demotion or does it?

We are trying to demote from Testing to Development. Not sure how it is suppose to behave. No entry in Lifecycle History about demotion, so getting confused.

Any explanation or links to documentation would be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Any insight into this functionality?

Comment: Any help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

The behavior which you experiencing is  due to the default implementation of  DemoteActionExecutor.java (it hasn't any implementation)

https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/trunk/components/governance/org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.extensions/src/org/wso2/carbon/governance/registry/extensions/executors/DemoteActionExecutor.java

You can extend the demote functionality using custom executor class and use that in the LC configuration instead of default DemoteActionExecutor.

Comment: Thanks for the response. How can i make it add a Entry in Lifecycle History that it was demoted? I just want an audit of Demote to see end to end workflow cycle.